# addRecordButton pop up dialogue form on image/button click outside jtable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

We have multiple jtables on one page. We want to have some external html element to be able to open "add new record" form dialog to add new record for particular jtable on click.

What is the best way to be able to achieve this? I tried following but its not working:

```
var jt= $('#myJTable').jtable({ })
```

```
<input type="image" id="addIcon" height="30px;" width="30px;" src="img/add.png"  / >
```

```
$('#addIcon').click(function() {
    jt.jtable.$("#dialog-form").dialog('open'); // this does not open dialog form of add new record
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using showCreateForm(). The answer was given by YamilBarcho on github.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#{ID_OF_YOUR_JTABLE}').jtable('showCreateForm');
```

might work!!